# Deployment of QML app with SoundEffect not working

Tags: qt, deployment, qml, qtmultimedia

I've to say... why is so hard to deploy Qt5 in OS X?

After a lot of pain... and discovering this script: https://gist.github.com/lasconic/5965542 and this custom macdeployqt: https://github.com/MaximAlien/macdeployqt I was able to deploy in OSX... but audio is not working.

I've a simple SoundEffect element:

SoundEffect {
    id: ring
    loops: 1
    source: "alarm03.wav"
}

it works fine running in debug/release mode from Qt Creator... but as soon as I run macdeployqt I start to get this error: **using null output device, none available
and no sound is played.**

Then I found that it could be the audio plugin missing... so I copied the plugins/audio folder to my app package.
Then I start to get an error in startup and the sound starts to play but it runs for about half second... and stops with another error.

The error in startup: http://pastebin.com/TFBgswfb

The error when try to play the sound: http://pastebin.com/KjQ3JCXJ

The error in startup I found that was because it was loading libraries from the app package and from my Qt installation (why??) so I renamed my installation folder to test... the error in startup disappeared... but the first error playing the sound returned.

So I'm out of ideas about what's happening... the only thing I know is that Qt needs a easier deployment system.

Versions: Qt 5.2 - Clang64 - Qt Creator 3.1

PS: My .pro file contains: 
**QT += sql multimedia**

Comment: You would need to show more code, I think.

Comment: When using `macdeployqt` with `QML` you need to add the option `-qml <PATH_TO_QML_SOURCES>` so that it can parse your files and deploy the necessary plugins too.

Comment: I did, my full command: /Applications/macdeployqt.app/Contents/MacOS/macdeployqt MyApp.app -dmg -qmldir=../MyApp/qml/MyApp/ The qml is being found and the window is rendered in the right way.

Comment: Some more code.
My .pro file: http://pastebin.com/tZCRDNGR
My core.js: http://pastebin.com/KX6mKh4c
My sound element in qml: http://pastebin.com/qRTAwSW3